# Matlab beginner: function that iterates a matrix

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop

I am a beginner of Matlab. I am trying to run this function but there seem to be a syntax error that I cannot understand. The source code is the following.

```
function print_trace(x)
for rowi=1:size(x,1),
    for coli=1:size(x,2),
        disp(x(rowi,coli))
    end
end
```

The error encountered is the following:

```
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.

Error in ==> print_trace at 2
for rowi=1:size(x,1),
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mzGD.jpg

EDIT 2:

Trying to see if there are multiple copies running:

```
>> which('print_trace')
C:\Users\stablum\Dropbox\cm\print_trace.m
```

EDIT: solution of the problem :)

it seems that I solved the problem, my mistake was running ("play" button) the file of the function instead of just calling the function (which will load the file automatically). I still don't understand why there was this error when the file is run, but at least my problem is solved.

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: the function is called like this: print_trace(matrixname)

Comment: the problem is that the error is encountered even before the function is called.

Comment: And `matrixname` has which value?

Comment: actually, the example call that I wrote is just an example of how it should be called (with 2d matrixes). The problem, actually, appears just when I am running the function itself, loading it in the environment.

Comment: Are the commas terminating the `for` lines really supposed to be there?

Comment: @francescostablum: OK you don't need to run the function to load it into the environment, while the file is in the **Current Folder**, you can use it like `print_trace(rand(3))` (type this in the Matlab command window and press enter, you will see the result in command window).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: it seems so, I followed this documentation: http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/matlab/control.html

Comment: @pm89: hmm, so if I change the function, once I save it, it's automatically loaded into the environment?

Comment: Are you pasting the text of the entire function into the command window?

Comment: @horchler: no, I am using a separated file, you can see it in this screenshot: http://imgur.com/pwPhzhh

Comment: Do you accidentally have multiple copies of the same file? Run `which('print_trace')` from the command window. Is the resultant path the same as that of the file you're editing?

Comment: @horchler: nope, just one: >> which('print_trace')
C:\Users\stablum\Dropbox\cm\print_trace.m

Comment: @francescostablum: yes it will, when you [**call**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) a function, it searches for a file with the same name of the function in the *current folder* or *Matlab path* and when it finds the file(function), it will run it with your input (and might return an output). There is no need to loading it. See [**calling a function**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html).

Comment: @pm89: thanks! it seems that I solved the problem, my mistake was running ("play" button) the file instead of just calling the function (which will load the file automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is because of the way you call the function.

The error indicates that you don't give the required parameter `x`. Especially, you seem t o call the function with

```
print_trace()
```

or

```
print_trace
```

or

```
print_trace(empty_cell{:})
```

which leads to the effect that there is no value to be assigned to `x`.

Comment: yes, but I don't even call the function. The problem appears when I run the function to be loaded in the environment. Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/pwPhzhh

Comment: you just run in the function (didn't call it, or send any input), and there is nothing in x! so the function don't know what to do when you ask her "size(x)", for example.