# What happens when a file is "run"

Tags: matlab, function

If I write a function in a .m file and try to run it by pressing the "run" button, will the function just be set in the environment or also run, maybe without arguments?

Comment: What happens when you try it? ;)

Comment: it happens the problem I am experiencing in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384048/matlab-beginner-function-that-iterates-a-matrix but seriously, I expect a very simple descriptive answer, just to understand how it works :)

Comment: Ask one question at a time please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function does not take any arguments, then it will simply be executed. If the function *does* take arguments, and you try to run it via the GUI, you should be prompted to enter a set of default arguments that should be used. These arguments will be used if you ever run the script in the future.

[image]

This is described in Matlab's documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-functions-in-the-editor.html).

Comment: +1: please also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384048/matlab-beginner-function-that-iterates-a-matrix#17384048) just asked by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of *mfiles* (files with `.m` extension) in Matlab: 
***Scripts*** and ***Functions***. (See [**Scripts vs. Functions**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html))

See [**Calling a function**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) for how to use a function programmatically.